# Conditions for convergence in probability of a sum

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

A sequence $\{X_n\}$ of random variables converges in probability towards the random variable $X$, Similarly, $\{Y_n\}$ converges in probability to $Y$. Under which conditions can I say that $\{X_n - Y_n\}$ converges to $X-Y$? 
Is there a theorem giving sufficient condition for this? Given that the examples of cases where this is not true seem very knife-edge.

Comment: A suitable $\epsilon, \delta, N_0$ argument, perhaps using $\frac{\delta}{2}$, should lead to a proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon,\delta>0$. By assumption there exists $N_0$ big enough so that $P(|X-X_n|>\varepsilon/2)<\delta/2$ and $P(|Y-Y_n|>\varepsilon/2)<\delta/2$ for all $n>N_0$. Then, for all $n>N_0$
\begin{align*}P(|X-Y-(X_n-Y_n)|>\varepsilon)&\leq P(|X-X_n|+|Y-Y_n|>\varepsilon)\\
&\leq P(|X-X_n|>\varepsilon/2)+P(|Y-Y_n|>\varepsilon/2)<\delta.
\end{align*}

Comment: So this argument shows that this is true for every X and every Y?

Comment: Unless I've made a terrible mistake somewhere then yes. More generally the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) ensures the result definitely holds for any $Y_n\to Y$ and $X_n\to X$.

Comment: If $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X $ and $Y_n \overset{p}{\to} Y$ then you can prove that  $(X_n, Y_n) \overset{p}{\to} (X, Y )$. There is a theorem (Continuous mapping theorem which says that if $f$ is a continuous function and $(X_n, Y_n) \overset{p}{\to} (X, Y)$ then $f(X_n, Y_n) \overset{p}{\to} f(X, Y)$. In particular the function f(x,y)= x-y is a continuous function.