# Cesaro sum convergence in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I saw in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931277/convergence-in-probability-and-convergence-of-cesaro-means)  that for random variables $\{X_n\}$ converging to 0 in probability it is not necessarily true that their Cesaro sum $\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots X_n}{n}$ converge in probability to 0. I am interested in sort of the converse of this. That is, if the Cesaro sum converge in probability to zero, then does the sequence $\{ (\frac{X_n}{n})_{n \geq 1} \}$ converge in probability to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ then
$$\frac{X_n}{n} = \frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}$$
Since $\frac{n-1}{n} \to 1$ you get that $\frac{X_n}{n} \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: Thanks! Can we see this directly from the definition of convergence in probability? I think we will have to show $P(\bigg|\frac{X_n}{n}\bigg| \geq \epsilon)=P(\bigg|\frac{S-n}{n}-\frac{n-1}{n}.\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-}\bigg| \geq \epsilon) \to 0$. How do I show the last equality? Should I use the inequality $|a-b| \geq |a|-|b|$

Comment: @abc See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665208/conditions-for-convergence-in-probability-of-a-sum) for example.

Comment: @abc I think you'll have to use $|a-b| \leq |a|+|b|$.